# Vagrant : Create new user and force the use of ssh keys for accessing the server

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I try to enforce the use of SSH keys in order to access the server (I disabled password-based login).

I use "ubuntu/trusty64" for my vagrant. After the first boot of my VM, I created another user "gwendal" and I added him to the sudo group.

Here are the steps I followed :

- [on my local computer] : `cd ~/.ssh` then `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C your@email.com -f id_gwendal` and I finally copied the content of `id_gwendal.pub`
- [on my guest] : I switch from vagrant to gwendal user and I pasted the public key to  `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

So I was supposed to be able to log in but I always have this message : 
Permission denied (publickey).

I tried :

- `ssh gwendal@192.168.22.10`
- `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_gwendal -o "IdentitiesOnly yes" gwendal@192.168.22.10`

Comment: check the ssh log on the VM. Did you remember to set the chmod on `authorized_keys` to  600 and `~/.ssh` to 700 ?

Comment: I already changed the chmod but it didn't fix the problem. I'll check the log

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion of Remus Rusanu I find the error.

When I check the last logs with `tail -500 /var/log/auth.log | grep 'sshd'` I noticed this:

> error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

So I checked the sshd_config file and there was this line (I didn't add myself):

```
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

So I simply commented the last line and I could access my server with my public key.